# Cannot GET /action_page.php? (Linking HTML Pages)

Tags: html, css

I have one html page (index.html) I am trying to link to another page (createprofile.html) using a button on the index page. I've tried onclick and using href, but when I click the button, and error appears on a blank white page that says Cannot GET /action_page.php?.

I've tried several ways to link these but it's simply not working...

```
Here is the index.html with the button I am trying to link (signupbtn).

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

    `enter code here`<link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">


    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="action_page.php" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome to Mission Connect!</h1>
        <p>Please create an account.</p>
        <hr>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label> <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" required>
    <br>
      <br>
    <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label> <br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="New Password" name="password" required>
    <br>
      <br>
    <label for="password"><b>Repeat Password</b></label> 
    <input type="password" placeholder="Re-enter New Password" name="password-repeat" required>

       <p>By creating an account you agree to our Terms & Privacy. </p>

      <div class="clearfix">
      <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <a href="createprofile.html"><button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Create My Account</button>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
    </form>
    </body></html>







And this is the html page (createprofile.html) I'm trying to link it to.








    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
    <h1>Welcome to Your Mission Connect Profile. </h1>
    <br>

    Select Profile Picture:
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit">
      </form>
      <br>
    <br>
       <form>
     First Name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="firstname">
     <br>
      <br>
     Last Name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <br>
     <br>
    Gender:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <br>
      Location:<br>
        <input type="text" name="location">
        <br>
       <br>
         Home Congregation:<br>
        <input type="text" name="homecongregation">
       <br>
       <br>
       Status:
       <br>
       <input type="radio" name="status" value="Preparing" checked> Preparing    (Pre-Missionary)<br>
       <input type="radio" name="status" value="InTheField"> In the Field (  (Current Missionary)<br>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="Supporting"> Supporting (Missionary Supporter)<br>
        <br>


    <br>
     Language(s):<br>
      <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="70">

     </textarea>
      <br> 
      <br>
      Location(s) of Interest:<br>
      <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="70">

     </textarea>

    <br>
    <br>
     Duration:
       <br>
       <input type="radio" name="duration" value="shortterm" checked>
 Short-  Term<br>
      <input type="radio" name="duration" value="longterm"> Long-Term<br>
     <input type="radio" name="duration" value="undecided"> Undecided<br>
      <br>
      <br>

      Why are you interested in missions?:<br>
      <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="70">
       </textarea>
     <br>
       <br>


      Describe your past missions experience(s):<br>
      <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="70">

       </textarea>



        </form>



How can I make these two pages link?
```

Answer (score 1):

your form action is /action_page.php where is your action_page.php ? just remove to form action `action_page.php` if you don't have any form action.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTML:

```
<form action="action_page.php"
```

The same thing would go with JSON but I wouldn't recommend.

If you want a button with a hyperlink for `<form action`:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Preview:
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

Try using these methods.